# Extract records from sql to table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i need to display my records from sql in table. In sql is saved records with - date, hour, subject. I have problem that i save everyone records to $record and i need only for example 2nd row with subject,date,hour to display to  10:00. I dont know count of rows, it can be else everyday. Check code and u will understand. Thank for help.

```
$time10 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM record WHERE slotDate = '$date' AND slotTime = '10:00'");
$time12 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM record WHERE slotDate = '$date' AND slotTime = '12:00'");
```

and there is html with php insert

```
<tr><!--FIRST RECORD OF 10:00-->
<td>
while($record = MySQL_Fetch_Row($time10)):
echo  $record[0];  echo "<p>";
echo  $record[1];  echo "<p>"; 
echo  $record[3];
</td>
</tr>

<tr><!--SECOND RECORD OF 10:00-->
<td> There i need 2nd row
</td>
</tr>

<tr><!--THIRD RECORD OF 12:00-->
<td> There i need for example 3rd row from TIME 12:00
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Your question makes no sense.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Add sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.) Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: its already done guys. Sorry... You can see my code

Answer (score 0):

Using an SQL query.

Please include more information so people can give better answers otherwise this type of answer is all you'll receive.

(user asking question updated their question after posting this sassy response.)

Answer (score 0):

```
$time10 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM record WHERE slotDate = '$date' AND slotTime = '10:00'");
echo '<table>';
echo '<tr><th>Date</th><th>Time</th><th>Subject</th></tr>';
while ($record = mysql_fetch_row($time10)) {
    echo '<tr><td>'.$record[0].</td><td>.$record[1].</td><td>.$record[2].'</td></tr>';    
}
echo '</table>';
```

It prints all records as table, where time is 10:00

If you need select only second row, try to use LIMIT first_row count_rows

```
$time10 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM record WHERE slotDate = '$date' AND slotTime = '10:00' LIMIT 1, 1");
```

Comment: Виталий Фадеев Thank you, but i need static table which will be display  all the time. There can be empty records at 10:00... :/

Comment: Use LIMIT in SQL to select a specific row from the database

Comment: I did it. But i have about 200commands for select from databaze. You has got 24 hours and in every hour has about 10 records.. So its about 24*10 comands SELECT from SQL